# Writing log in file and display it on console at the same time

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

here is my `logback-spring.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<appender name="DEBUG_FILE" 
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <file>./target/log/app-debug.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>./log/target/app-debug.log-%d.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
         <pattern>%-30(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ERROR_FILE" 
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <file>./target/log/app-error.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>./target/log/app-error.log-%d.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
         <pattern>%-30(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE"/>
</root>    
<root level="ERROR"> 
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_FILE"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

Now everything log correctly but I am unable to see INFO level on my console while running the app. I still have

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
  file:
    name: ./log/app.log
```

in my `.yml` file but there is no whatsoever logging on console.

Can I write the log in file and display it on the console at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ConsoleAppender in your existing logback config. Below is a small snippet for your reference,

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
    <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
    </Pattern>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

And you can control the root log level and also include the reference of your appender "DEBUG_FILE" as well to print in the console in addition to the implementation which you have done to write in a file. Below snippet is set to info to match your use case,

```
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE" />
  </root>
```